# How to set 777 permission on a particular folder in Homestead?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, vagrant, homestead

I am using [phpjasper](https://github.com/geekcom/phpjasper) package and I need to set the permission of the following folder to 777:

```
/vendor/geekcom/phpjasper/src/JasperStarter/bin
```

and the file binary

```
 jasperstarter
```

I am using Homestead.

how can I set it?

Answer (score 2):

By executing this code in the linux console:

```
 chmod 777 /vendor/geekcom/phpjasper/src/JasperStarter/bin
```

Or by using chmod directly in php, but you may not have permissions to fo that through php

Answer (score 2):

Try this Command in your Linux terminal.

**cd /vendor/geekcom/phpjasper/src**

**chmod -R 777 jasperstarter/**

Answer (score 0):

Try this Command,

```
cd /vendor/geekcom/phpjasper/src

sudo chmod -R 777 jasperstarter/
```

It will ask for password.